# In $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$, show that $([a]_m)^{qd+r} = (([a]_m)^d)^q([a]_m)^r$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$, show that $([a]_m)^{qd+r} = (([a]_m)^d)^q([a]_m)^r$.

My first attempt at this question was to use simple arithmetic properties to prove this true, however, this is incorrect.

What is the best way to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use
$$([a]_m)^{qd+r}=\underbrace{[a]_m[a]_m\cdots[a]_m}_{qd+r\textrm{ times}}=_*[a^{qd+r}]_m=[(a^d)^qa^r]_m$$
where $(*)$ happens by definition.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but then wouldn't it entail proving $([a^d])([a^q]) = [a^{qd}]$?

Comment: If so, then how would that be proven?

Answer (score 0):

Start by showing the following is well-defined:
$$[x]_m \cdot [y]_m = [x\cdot y]_m$$

That is, if you take representatives $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $[x_1]_m = [x_2]_m$ and $[y_1]_m = [y_2]_m,$ then
$$x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2 = (x_1-x_2)y_1 + x_2(y_1-y_2)$$
is divisible by $m.$

---

This property allows us to write
$$([a]_m)^n = [a^n]_m$$
and these two statements together allow you to use those simple arithmetic properties to prove your statement.